# Python Replace Not working in the code

Tags: python

Given a string s, return a string

where all occurences of its first char have

been changed to '*', except do not change

the first char itself.

e.g. 'babble' yields 'ba**le'

Assume that the string is length 1 or more.

```
def fix_start(s):
MyString = s[1:]
for charr in MyString:
    if charr == s[0]:
        s.replace(charr,'*')
return s
```

**Whats Wrong with what i did**

Comment: First, your indentation is wrong. Second, `replace` returns a new string, it doesn't alter the one you call the method on. Third, the way you're using `replace` in a `for` loop doesn't make sense. `replace` replaces *all* matching characters in the string.

Answer (score 1):

When you replace the character in the string s with s.replace, this returns a new string (and do not update s itself). Then, you should add s = s.replace(...).
You can also write as:

```
def fix_start(s): 
    return s[0]+s[1:].replace(s[0],'*')

res=fix_start('babble') 
print(res)
```

`
so that you don't have to do the for loop on all characters of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with one line. Try:

```
def fix_start(s):
    return s[0] + s[1:].replace(s[0], '*')
```